# Set of constants such that trigonometric equation always sums to zero

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Consider the equation:
>
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \cos( x + a_i) = 0$$
> Where the above identity holds for all $x$ $\in$ R, how much solutions set of constants are possible to make the equation zero i.e: sequence of $a_i$ for a given $n$? Find all such sequences.

A question I came up with myself, I'll post my work about the question and hopefully,  someone else can help me finish.

---

Consider,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \cos(x + a_i) = 0 \tag{1}$$

Differentiate with $x$ (remember defined for all $x \in R$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sin(x + a_i) = 0 \tag{2}$$

Combining (1) and (2),

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n e^{j(x+a_i)} = 0$$

For the identity to hold for all $x$,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n e^{ja_i} = 0$$

If we consider complex numbers as vectors, then a trivial solution to the above equation is by application of [polygon rule of vector addition](https://cnx.org/contents/Qk0ZZlcl@7/Vector-addition). Eg: for n=3, find three-unit complex numbers that form a triangle, n=4 find four-unit complex numbers forming a square. If so, then we can think of the sequence of $ a_i$ as an arithmetic progression characterized by a common difference and a starting term $a_1$. I.e:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n e^{j(a_1 + (n-1)d)} = 0$$

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out what the common difference should be...

Other than that, are there 'other kind' of solutions to the problem statement?

Comment: It seems that, if you can find one tuple $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ and another tuple $(b_i)_{i=1}^m$, then the $m+n$-tuple made up of both $a$'s and $b$'s will also be a solution. Thus, the real question is - if you have a tuple of $a$'s that satisfies your identity - can it always be broken into smaller tuples where each tuple is an arithmetic progression of the type you are mentioning. (I don't know the answer.)

Comment: Nice observation @StinkingBishop

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

For $n=2$ there is a unique solution up to the rotation moving one of the element to $1$. Same thing for $n=3$.

For $n =2p$ even, the are an infinite number of solutions up to a rotation: it is sufficient to be able to pair elements diametrically opposed.

For $n=2p+1 \gt 3$, just take $3$ elements positioned on an equilateral triangle plus an even number of elements positioned as just above.

*Need to see what kind of other solutions exist...*